# Calculate $E(X)$ and $\sigma(X)$ for a simple urn problem

Tags: self-study, moments, arithmetic

In a box there are 4 red and 7 green balls.  A random sample of 5 of the balls is made.  Let the number of red balls in the sample be $X$ (a random variable).  Calculate $E(X)$ and $\sigma(X)$

Comment: Please indicate what *specific* help you need with this problem: where are you stuck?

Comment: We welcome questions like this, @Gio, but we treat them differently. Please tell us what you understand thus far & where you are stuck, & we'll try to provide hints to get you unstuck. To better understand the process, you should read the [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for the [tag:self-study] tag.

Comment: I am confused as to how to calculate the standard deviation

Comment: Start with the sample space. What are the possible values for $X?$ For $X^2?$

Comment: This problem can be modeled by drawing a *single* ticket out of a box with $\binom{11}{5}=462$ tickets, one for each possible sample of $5$ balls. On $\binom{4}{0}\binom{7}{5}=21$ of those tickets, corresponding to the samples with $0$ red and $5$ green balls, the number $0$ is written. On $\binom{4}{1}\binom{7}{4}=140$, corresponding to all possible samples with $1$ red ball, are written the number $1$. Likewise, $210$ tickets bear the number $2$, $84$ the number $3$, and $7$ the number $4$. What is the standard deviation of the numbers in this box?